# How Many Homomorphisms $\Bbb{Z}_4 \to \Bbb{Z}_8 \times \Bbb{Z}_{12} \times \Bbb{Z}_{15}$?

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

I know that the number of homomorphisms between $Z_n$ and $Z_m$ is $\gcd(m,n)$. However, I don't know what to do with these two questions:

> 1. How many different homomorphisms exist: $\Bbb{Z}_4 \to \Bbb{Z}_8 \times \Bbb{Z}_{12} \times \Bbb{Z}_{15}$
> 2. How many different homomorphisms exist: $\Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \to \Bbb{Z}_8 \times \Bbb{Z}$

Any tips?

Comment: Hint: Think about where the generators of the groups in the domain can go.  Your edit is wrong: $\mathbb{Z}$ is *not* $\mathbb{Z}_1$.  $\Bbb{Z}_8 \times \Bbb{Z}$ is **not** isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}$. $\mathbb{Z}$ is cyclic and $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}$ isn't, for instance.

Comment: @SpamIAm You're right, thanks.

Comment: If $x$ in the domain has order $n$, what can the order of $\phi(x)$ be?

Comment: $\phi(x)$ has to be a divisor of $n$, right?

Comment: Right! Now just think about what that means for the generators.

Comment: Hint: Any homomorphism $h:\Bbb Z_4\to G$ is completely determined by $h(1)$.

Answer (score 5):

A homomorphism into a direct product is essentially the same as a collection of homomorphisms (one for each factor). Similarly, a homomorphism from a direct product is the same as a collection of homomorphisms, one from each factor. (To be precise: We are talking of products with finitely many factors here).

So for 1. check: How many homomorphsims are there $\mathbb Z_4\to\mathbb Z_8$? $\mathbb Z_4\to\mathbb Z_{12}$? $\mathbb Z_4\to\mathbb Z_{15}$?

And for 2. check: How many homomorphisms are there $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\to \mathbb Z_8$? (You may count the homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_2\to\mathbb Z_8$) first). And how many homomorphisms are there $\mathbb Z_2\times\mathbb Z_2\to \mathbb Z$? (You may count the homomorphisms $\mathbb Z_2\to\mathbb Z$) first).

Comment: For 1., there are 4, 4, and 1 homomorphisms. So then is the number of homomorphisms $Z_2 \to Z_4 \times Z_{12} \times Z_{15} = 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 1= 16$? How do I put together the numbers of homomorphisms?

Comment: Also, how do I count the number of homomorphisms $Z_2 \to Z$?

Comment: @Newb Any homomorphism $h:\Bbb Z_2\to \Bbb Z$ is completely determined by $h(1)$, and furthermore one must have $h(1) + h(1) = h(1+1) = h(0) = 0$, which narrows down the possibilities quite a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: This solution is most probably overkill.

Dealing with abelian groups, we are right in the context of homological algebra. One of the main characters in homological algebra is the functor ${\rm Hom}(A,-):\mathbf{Ab}\to\mathbf{Ab}$ assigning to an abelian group $B$ the abelian group ${\rm Hom}(A,B)$ of group homomorphisms $A\to B$ and it's contravariant counterpart ${\rm Hom}(-,B):\mathbf{Ab}\to\mathbf{Ab}$ assigning to an abelian group $A$ the group ${\rm Hom}(A,B)$. Two of the first properties we can prove are
$$
{\rm Hom}\left(A, \prod_{i\in I} B_i\right) \cong \prod_{i\in I} {\rm Hom}(A,B_i),
$$
$$
{\rm Hom}\left(\bigoplus_{i\in I} A_i, B\right) \cong \prod_{i\in I} {\rm Hom}(A_i,B).
$$

(Note that for finite products $\bigoplus$ and $\prod$ are isomorphic.)

This is the fact Hagen von Eitzen mentioned, when he said, that a homomorphism into a product is a familiy of homomorphisms into each factor and a homomorphism from a product is a family of homomorphisms from each factor. Together with the classification theorem for finitely generated abelian groups, this boils all the ${\rm Hom}$-groups between those down to the following:
\begin{align*}
{\rm Hom}(\ \mathbb Z\ ,\ \mathbb Z\ )&\cong \mathbb Z,\\
{\rm Hom}(\ \mathbb Z\ , \mathbb Z_n)&\cong \mathbb Z_n,\\
{\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_n,\ \mathbb Z\ )&\cong 0,\\
{\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_n, \mathbb Z_m)&\cong \mathbb Z_d \quad\text{where $d=\gcd(n,m)$}.
\end{align*}
Proving these is essentially what you are doing in your exercise in the general case.

Together you come up with

\begin{align*}{\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_4, \mathbb Z_8 \times \mathbb Z_{12} \times \mathbb Z_{15})
&\cong
{\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_4, \mathbb Z_8) \times {\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_4, \mathbb Z_{12}) \times {\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_4, \mathbb Z_{15})
\\&\cong \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_1 \cong \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4,
\\
{\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_2 \times\mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_8 \times\mathbb Z)
&\cong
{\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_2 \times\mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_8) \times\underbrace{{\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_2 \times\mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z)}_0
\\&\cong {\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_8) \times {\rm Hom}(\mathbb Z_2, \mathbb Z_8) \cong \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2.
\end{align*}

Thus the answers to your questions are $16$ and $4$.